C++ Undefined behaviour in vector access
Following up the p0532r0.pdf documentation the following piece of code results in UB
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct X {
    const int i;
    X(int _i) : i(_i) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const X& x) {
    return os << x.i;
    };
};
int main(){
    std::vector<X> v;
    v.push_back(X(42));
    v.clear();
    v.push_back(X(77));
    std::cout << v[0]; // undefined behaviour
}

However no UB is detected when the above piece of code is run with sanitiser.
demo
Why does  compiler not detect this error? Apart from that based on the P0532R0, when type of vector is a class that has  a const member , the internal usage of placement new  causes UB. How is  this issue  overcome ?

There can be many reasons. Only the compiler vendor can say for sure.  You can tag gcc and also report this on gnu.gcc since you're already aware this is UB.

How is this issue overcome, It isn't: Thus, std::launder() doesn’t solve the problem to avoid undefined behavior in allocator-based containers when having elements with constant/reference members  The implementation just knows that it wont be any issue since they have control and know the const object wont still be there.

No tool will detect all cases of UB.

It's out of date. As of c++20, placement new of a struct containing a const variable is no longer UB. However, doing additional pushes will fail because the needed member functions for a reallocation are deleted.

the internal usage of placement new causes UB
If the compiler uses placement new to overwrite the vector's first element this is no longer UB as of C++ 20. Placement new is allowed to "transparently replace" const values so long as it is not a top level const. Also, std::launder is no longer needed for access. See basic life for details on transparent replacement.
However, the copy assignment operator is automatically deleted so the vector object can no longer be resized for instance by adding additional elements that exceed the vector's capacity.
See this discussion on how to write a custom copy assigment operator to handle classes with const or reference objects.

Thank you for the answer. In our case does the 8.3 apply ? o
1 is not a complete const object

Yes, o1 is not a complete const object. So 8.3 applies. It would be if std::vector<const X> v; however, that's not allowed since vector's allocator requires that the object not be const. It may, however, be an object that contains a const.

Firstly, this behaviour is undefined by the standard (up to and including C++17), but is implicitly well-defined on GCC (and everywhere from C++20). From your linked PDF:

AFAIK, gcc currently does not optimize the constant/reference case, but does optimizations for the vptr part.

So in a sense there's nothing to detect.
Secondly, the reason this UB is not detected by ubsan: it doesn't check for it at all in the first place.
The manual (for 9.5) lists the behaviours checked by ubsan here, and links the equivalent clang ubsan documentation.
Neither claim to detect the particular un-laundered access to a placement-new overwritten object with a const member that you're concerned with.
BTW, Your demo is using GCC 9.1. None of this changes with later versions up to and including trunk AFAICS, but that's why I linked the 9.5 manual.

But based on the P0532R0 the way of allocating memory results in UB when const is used

ubsan checks a bunch of possible undefined behaviour cases. It doesn't promise to find all possible UB.

FWIW, ubsan does have -fsanitize=vptr and that's the case P0532R0 says GCC would also try to optimize. So maybe you can get a working example using that instead of a const member.
